# microservices jhipster registry Rest Api's for non-Jvm registration

Tags: jhipster, netflix-eureka

Is there a way to register non-jvm application in jhipster registry using Rest endpoints,something like [https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations](http://Eureka%20Rest%20Api)

Or can we integrate Netflix Prana to expose over HTTP

Sidecar could be a another possible approach, but its an overhead maintaining on the host server.

Please suggest which one would be the best approach for non-jvm application.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch from Eureka to to Consul as it is also supported by Spring Cloud and JHipster, for non JVM apps Consul offers more options like DNS lookup or Consul templates.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gael!